# “The tongue in a certain state will cleave to the roof”

Tags: sentence

While looking for synonym comparison of “stick-cleave-adhere”, I came across this in [English Synonyms Explained in Alphabetical Order](https://archive.org/details/englishsynonymse00crabuoft):

> To stick expresses more than to cleave, and cleave than adhere: things
>   are made to stick either by incision into the substance, or through
>   the intervention of some glutinous matter; they are made to cleave and
>   adhere by the intervention of some foreign body: what sicks,
>   therefore, becomes so fast joined as to render the bodies inseparable;
>   what cleaves and adheres is less tightly bound, and more easily
>   separable.
>
> Two pieces of clay will stick together by tho incorporation of the
>   substance in the two parts; paper is made to stick to paper by means
>   of glue: the tongue in a certain state will cleave to the roof: paste,
>   or even occasional moisture, will make soft substances adhere to each
>   other, or to hard bodies.

What does “the tongue in a certain state will cleave to the roof” mean?

Comment: If the author had added "of the mouth" so that the whole quote is "the tongue in a certain state will cleave to the roof of the mouth", would that help?

Comment: While eating a peanut butter sandwich, you may notice some difficult in separating you tongue from the roof of you mouth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are referring to a human tongue cleaving to the roof of the mouth under certain circumstances. Originally I suggested this occurring when making a "tsk" sound but was rightfully corrected that in such a case it would not be considered "cleaving" due to the absence of a foreign body.

Comment: +1, but I think the vacuum blurs the line between foreign body and adhesive. Pedantry doesn't bridge the gap between language and real physics.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was worried because Webster gives this definition of “tongue”: a tapering flame.

Comment: @PatrickM I'm not sure what you mean by blurring the line between foreign body and adhesive. The reason I included the vacuum is that it's the vehicle of cleaving. This is adhesion without the help of a foreign body because a vacuum is the absence of a foreign body (air). A vacuum explains "a certain state" in which the tongue cleaves to the roof, as is done when making a 'tsk tsk' sound.

Comment: According to the cited definition, cleaving happens from the intervention of a foreign body; a vacuum is the absence of *everything* really, so it doesn't quite fit the role of the thing doing the cleaving, according to the definition. However, a vacuum is a *thing* in the sense that it is a noun in the English language. My point was that there is a gap between the very fine nuance the author tries to draw between stick, cleave and adhere and the physical reality of the situation of a tongue cleaving to the roof of the mouth.

Comment: Maybe the state the author meant was the tongue being covered in peanut butter? It's a surprisingly inexact example for the very exact differences drawn between the three words.

Comment: @PatrickM Ah I understand, and I agree it's a vague "state" in the original quotation. So really a tongue can cleave to the mouth (with peanut butter as you describe), but in my specific example I couldn't call it cleaving. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think CobaltDuck has the context correct.

> the tongue in a certain state will cleave to the roof of the mouth

Consider that with the cited definition of cleave:

> [the tongue and the roof of the mouth] are made to cleave and adhere by the intervention of some foreign body

I think the author is driving at: "You can force the tongue upwards and make it cleave to the roof of the mouth, close your mouth tightly so you jaw forces them together, or lodging something under the tongue can force it to cleave to the roof of the mouth."

Answer (score 0):

I woke up in the middle of the night and my mouth was so dry I could not move my tongue from the roof of my mouth and hardly open my lips. I could not salivate until I had sucked some water though the slight gap in my lips and got everything working again. A most unpleasant experience.

Comment: This looks more like a comment on the other posts than an answer to the question.